# streaming video from a python server to a web client

Tags: python, html

How do I stream a video from a python server to an html page web client (nodejs)?

I'm using a node js web project and I'm just writing frames with python and reading them with javascript but I can't use a high frame rate nor a high resolution.

Thanks for helping. This is the code I'm using to read the frame:

```
var button = document.getElementById('play');


button.addEventListener('click', function refresh() {

  document.getElementById("myimg").src = "images/color_img.jpg?" + new Date().getTime();
   v= setTimeout(refresh, 100);
});

var button2 = document.getElementById('pause');
button2.addEventListener('click', function myStopFunction() {
  clearTimeout(v);
});
```

Comment: How you wanna do it in backend? in front and html the code is simple : <video id="videoPlayer" controls>
  <source src="http://localhost:3000/video" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Comment: but how to stream in port 3000 using python ??

Comment: pure python?? no Flask nor Django

Comment: well to be clear i m using python to process a video (AI-YOLO) so i want to stream the output video in a html page(im using nodejs as a wen server )

Comment: what do you mean process with python? this link provides live streaming (if python is generating residue frames) and everything you need with nodejs https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-media-server, actually I highly recommend using docker to deploy easily

Comment: ok thank you  in fact im already using a docker and i will change the web server to flask( i  mswitching to flask instead of nodejs) and thank you for you help i really appreciate it.

Comment: what is your flask library name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks guys this is solved im using this python (flask) code to stream live feed from web cam :

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2
import sys
import numpy

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_frame():
    camera_port=0
    camera=cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port) #this makes a web cam object

    while True:
        retval, im = camera.read()
        imgencode=cv2.imencode('.jpg',im)[1]
        stringData=imgencode.tostring()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
            b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n'+stringData+b'\r\n')

    del(camera)

@app.route('/vid')
def vid():
     return Response(get_frame(),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost',port=5000, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

code written by mr Mohit Kumar i found it on youtube .

to retrieve the live feed i m using

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/vid">
```

note : you have to specify clearly the protocole used.
       also it doesn't matter what web framework you are using (it worked on nodejs and flask)
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

First you use simple tag in html :

```
<video id="videoPlayer" controls> <source src="localhost:3000/video" type="video/mp4"> </video>
```

this [link](https://npmjs.com/package/node-media-server) provides live streaming (if python is generating residue frames) and everything you need with nodejs, actually I highly recommend using docker to deploy easily